# How to add collections to solr core?

Tags: tomcat, solr, tomcat7

I want to add one more collection to solr core. I need blogs for examples and suggestions.

I am using Tomcat 7 and Ubuntu for this.

Though it is mentioned in the wikies about how to install Solr and create cores, there's no complete view about how to create collection under the same core.

How to add Solr collection in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, just copy/paste exist collection, and rename this copy, for instance *collection2*. Also do not forget edit **core.properties** file, put there new collection's name.

Comment: Copy-paste from where to where?

Answer (score 2):

Core and Collection is basically the same where you would hold the information pertaining to different unrelated entities.

You would have different Cores/Collections for e.g. Documents, People, News etc...
You can always club information within the same Core/Collection e.g. Document & People etc.
It would really depend on how you index your data and what the requirements are.

You need to check Solr Multicore feature, which allows you to setup multiple cores/collections

You can find multiple blogs about [Multicore setup](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Configuring+solr.xml#Configuringsolr.xml-UsingMultipleSolrCores)

You can [download](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/home/PDF+Versions) the book from LucidWorks as well for more detailed information

Answer (score 2):

if your one collection is present inside example/solr directory, then you can create another collection inside the same example/solr directory. Do note that it is not strictly multicore since all the collections are present inside the same core and so all the collections will share the same solr.war file. The collections directory would have their own subdirectories :- conf and data. Also, each collection should have its own schema.xml and solrconfig.xml

for example, assume you have two collections  :- collection1 and collection2 inside example/solr directory. Then you can call them by :-

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?parameters

http://localhost:8983/solr/collection2/select?parameters
```

once you have created all the collections, you will have to modify the solr.xml file in example/solr directory. Look to the core child tag in cores name xml tag and add the new collection there.

```
<core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />
<core name="collection2" instanceDir="collection2" />
```

The instanceDirs are the name of the directories in which your cores are present.

Comment: can you please say how to create a new collection . you say "once you have created all the collections" but the problem is just that: how to create a new collection. Do i need to duplicate the folder of collection1 and rename it to collection2 ?

Comment: yup. that is it. copy the collection1 directory and rename it to collection2. each collection will have its own schema and solrconfig file. Once that is setup, then edit your solr.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create it from console with:

```
solr create -с collection2
```

In linux you should run it from *solr* user

```
sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c collection2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As Max mentions, the top of this URL will help you

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml

Also I have only briefly read ApacheSolrRefGuide-v4.1.pdf http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/home/PDF+Versions but it has helped me no end in understanding how Solr should be setup on the server and how you add multiple cores, see pg. 398

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 4.x simply create [`solr.xml`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20%28supported%20through%204.x%29) under your `solr.home`, for example:

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
  <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

In Solr 5.x the cores should be automatically discovered when you create [`core.properties`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties) file anywhere under your `solr.home` directory and add `name=my_core_name` property inside it.